# QML Layout not limiting width of children

Tags: qt, layout, qml

I have a QML ColumnLayout with a few children, and I want to limit its width, like so:

```
ColumnLayout {

    width: 360
    height: 480

    ColumnLayout {
        id: inner
        Layout.maximumWidth: 200
        Layout.fillHeight: true

        Text {
            text: "Welcome"
            font.pixelSize: 18
        }

        Text {
            text: "Long explanation that should wrap, but ends up overflowing layout"
            wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: inner
        z: -1
        border.color: "orange"
    }

}
```

I get the result shown in the picture below.

[image]

The orange box shows the dimensions of the inner layout item, which is all right. However, the children text of the layout is not wrapped.

I can only fix that by adding

```
Layout.maximumWidth: parent.width
```

to my 'Text' items, but that's quite awkward approach. Am I doing anything wrong, or is this a Qt bug, or is it a design approach for some reason? I am using Qt 5.4.1.

Answer (score 2):

> The text will only wrap if an explicit width has been set

[Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#wrapMode-prop)

```
Text
{
    width: parent.width
}
```

Comment: Please try your code before you post it: `Invalid property assignment: "contentWidth" is a read-only property`

Comment: (It's `Layout.fillWidth: true`)

Comment: It does not seem the comment in docs is accurate. The "maximumWidth" workaround does work, which suggests that the layout code is capable of setting width itself, and that causes wrapping to happen. I don't necessary have to set 'width' myself explicitly in QML code.

Comment: Also, adding "width: parent.width" to every Text item is slightly shorter, but fundamentally just as awkward as adding "Layout.maximumWidth: parent.width" - the natural behavior of a layout is to force children to stay inside its bounds, which is quite possible with wrapping labels and which is how layouts in Qt Widgets work.

Comment: I think the docs are correct. The `maximumWidth` approach probably works because the layout (`ColumnLayout`, not the text layout functionality of `Text`) will see that the implicit width of the text is too large and explicitly set the width to be smaller. In other words, it's effectively the same as `width: parent.width` or `Layout.fillWidth: true`. Personally, I prefer the approach listed in your question, as you should use the attached `Layout` properties if your items are in a layout.